# Textbox on which Keys Delete and backspace Works

Tags: c#

I need to have a text box on which events of Delete and Backspace works.Is it possible to  have such a text box in C#,or restrict the behavior of text box in such a way. Other keys do not work.

Comment: Can't you use TextChanged Event ??

Comment: wpf? winforms? asp.net?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`TextBox.KeyPress`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.windows.forms.control.keypress.aspx) event:

```
    private void textBox1_KeyPress(object sender, System.Windows.Forms.KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Delete || e.KeyCode == Keys.Back)
        {
            // your stuff
        }
        e.Handled = true;
    }
```

Comment: This is very bad, because the typed key will still be displayed

Comment: is it possible to use keypress event. ?? since am using c1 Textbox am not able to get this e.KeyCode  on _Keypres Event

Comment: KeyPress does not expose prooerty e.KeyCode

Answer (score 0):

For winforms you can do it like this:

```
protected void myTextBox_KeyPress(object sender, System.Windows.Forms.KeyPressEventArgs e)
{
    e.Handled = !IsValidCharacter(e.KeyChar);
}

private bool IsValidCharacter(Keys c)
{
    bool isValid = false;

    if (c == Keys.Space)
    {
       isValid = true;
    }   
   return isValid; 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want delete key works ..

```
private void textBox1_KeyDown(object sender, System.Windows.Forms.KeyEventArgs e)
{
    Keys k = e.KeyCode

    If Not (k = Keys.Back Or k = Keys.Delete)
    {
        e.Handled = True
    }        
}
```